# Maximum likelihood in uniform distribution

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
data=load ('Q2Even');
histogram(data.y)
phat = mle(data.y,'distribution','normal')
```

data is continuous. And it follows a uniform distribution when I create the histogram. I have to find maximum likelihood of variance and mean parameters. When I use mle, it gives me a row vector stating:

```
phat =

   26.9900    7.3849
```

To my knowledge, these are parameters of uniform distribution i-e mean and variance.Correct me if I'm wrong.
Is there a function in matlab which could give me maximum likelihood of mean and variance?

Comment: `mle(data.y,'distribution','normal')` why use `'normal'` if your data comes from a uniform distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You are stating that your distribution is uniform and continuous, but you have passed `normal` as the distribution to the MLE function. The paramater estimates you will receive will therefore be mean and standard deviation as those are the MLE parameters for a normally distributed continuous distribution. If you rerun and enter `phat = mle(data.y,'distribution','unif')` you will get a vector for the parameters a and b which are the lower and upper endpoints (respectively) of the distribution. Check out the documentation on the mathworks site for [MLE](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mle.html#outputarg_phat) further clarification.